# Exploding String And remove multiple entry

Tags: php

Thing is, I want to make a script that first register a string from The POST Data from a form and then check whether there is a multiple entry. If any, that entry will be removed and fresh list of unique entry will be proceed.

- The Entries are URL. A list of URL and there might be a multiple entry.

  ```
  $sites=$_POST['sitelist'];

  $sites=explode("\n", $sites);
  ```

The `$_POST['sitelist']` came from a Textarea from a submitted from. Now how can i separate all those URL and Check whether a URL came again and then Remove it and Proceed with a fresh list of URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sites = preg_split('~\\s+~', trim($sites)); // Split by all consecutive spaces
// Uncomment next line for superficial URL validation
// $sites = preg_grep('~^https?://.+?/.*~i', $sites);
$sites = array_unique($sites); // Keep uniques
```

This splits the list of URLs by all spaces *(URLs don't have spaces and spaces include line separators)*. Does not keep empty rows and has optional sanitation.

Answer (score 3):

Test this:

```
$sites=array_unique(explode("\n", $sites));
```

Comment: Seriously i don't even know there is a function called `array_unique`. Thanks man.

Comment: This will keep empty/blank rows. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`array_unique` filters an array of duplicates, so once you've split it by newlines, all exact duplicates should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_unique()`:

`$sites = array_unique($sites);`

Comment: you all beat me ;)  It's worth noting though that PHP has lots of built-in functions for all kinds of stuff newbies to the language might not realize. If you're trying to figure out how to do something that seems pretty simple, search php.net!